# How can I find the number of points of those three elliptic curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves, projective-space

Let $y^2=x^3$ the affine cubic in $\mathbb{A}^2(k)$ where $k$ is a finite field with cardinal $q=\# k$. I'm trying to express the number of points of the cubic in terms of $q=\# k$.

I'm trying this: there is of course $(x,y)= (0,0)$. If $x,y$ are non zero, then there are $1+2 \frac{q-1}{2}=q$ quadratic residues $x$.

To find the number of solutions of the equivalent projective version of the curve $y^2z=x^3 \in \mathbb{P}^2(k)$, I find $q^2+q+1$ coordinate points. Do you think it's correct ?

Do you know how I can find the number of affine points of the curve $y(y-1)=x^3 \in \mathbb{A}^2(k)$ or do you know a method I could use ?

I thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Is $p$ a prime or it can be the power of a prime?

Comment: $p$, (I should have set $q$), is the cardinal of any finite field. It can be a prime or a power of prime.

Comment: $g$ a generator of $\Bbb{F}_q^*$ and $\chi_3(g^n)=  e^{2i \pi n / 3}$ then $\chi_3(a)+\chi_3(a)^2+\chi_3(a)^3 = 3_{a \in \Bbb{F}_q^{*3}}$ from which if $3 |q-1$ then $\sum_{(x,y) \in \Bbb{F}_q^* \times \Bbb{F}_q, x^3=y(y-1)} 1 = \sum_{y\in  \Bbb{F}_q} \chi_3(y(y-1))+\chi_3(y(y-1))^2+\chi_3(y(y-1))^3$ which is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_sum searching for 'jacobi sum elliptic curves' you'll find many results